Deploy transact not payable with Remix
I can't click Deploy, even though my Metamask is connected:

My Metamask currently has 0.2497 SepoliaETh in it.

Since, the constructor of the contract that you’re trying to deploy is not payable, therefore it’s not allowing the value to be passed while deploying.
Remove the VALUE that you’ve entered as 10 in your Remix IDE:


Removed it (it is now 0), still have the same error

Can you share the contract code by creating a gist of the same ?

I had this same issue and came across this. It was very frustrating and I tried many different changes in the settings and nothing worked. What did work was the following:

Open Metamask
Disconnect Account from Remix
Reconnect account to Remix
Deploy success

If anyone else comes across this issue I hope the above resolves it for you and saves you some time.

Disconnecting and reconnecting my metamask to remix solved the problem. SpaceTristan's answer did the job
